# Attribute raises NoSuchElementException in selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, attributes, nosuchelementexception

I can get the element which attribute contains `X` but I can't get the attribute itself. Why?

This code does not raise any errors:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Conversations"]//a[contains(@data-href, "https://www.messenger.com/t/")]')
```

This code raises `NoSuchElementException` error:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Conversations"]//a[contains(@data-href, "https://www.messenger.com/t/")]/@data-href')
```

This code is extracted from Messenger main page with the chats. I would like to get all links in the `ul` list...
I don't get it... Any help please?

Comment: Did you try to wait for the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the links data-href value you need to traverse links elements and use the `get_attribute()`

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Conversations"]//a[contains(@data-href, "https://www.messenger.com/t/")]')
ul_list=[link.get_attribute("data-href") for link in links]
print(ul_list)
```

Comment: I've used get_attribute("data-href") after the code and it was not working, here it works, thanks !

Comment: Great to know it worked.Please upvote the answer if this helps future reader.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
lists=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@aria-label="Conversations"]//a[contains(@data-href, "https://www.messenger.com/t/")]/@data-href')))
 for element in lists:
      print element.text
```

**Note**: Add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```